# Kotlin and Spring boot, transient properties not initialized properly

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, nullpointerexception, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring boot with a DDD application, in which each aggregate root entity has a transient field called events, which are not persisted in database:

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class AggregateRoot<TId>(id: TId) : DomainModel<TId>(id) {

    @Transient
    private var events : MutableList<DomainEvent> = mutableListOf()

    fun occurredEvents(): List<DomainEvent>{
        val events = this.events.toMutableList()
        this.events.clear()
        return events
    }

    fun addEvent(event: DomainEvent){
        events.add(event)
    }

    fun removeEvent(event: DomainEvent){
        events.remove(event)
    }
}
```

It works fine when I add new entities by composing it myself. But when I load an entity with finder methods from repository, it appears that the transient property **events** is null, instead of a mutable list. This gave me a null pointer exception that took me a while to find out why it happened.

I tried to change it to lateinit property and it would not work. The only workaround I have so far is to add a null check for each methods that involve events and initialize it, but this solution is suboptimal(the funny thing is, when I package it with Maven, it warns me that condition of null is always false, but it happens to be true):

```
if(events == null) events = mutableListOf()
```

I wonder if there is a better way to handle this problem? Maybe @Transient is the issue here? Or perhaps a custom initializer will help? Anyone know how to solve this problem in a good and elegant Kotlin way, instead of a dumb null check?

Answer (score -1):

Move initialization into a separate method and annotate it with `@PostConstruct`.

Comment: Entities are not managed beans.

Answer (score -1):

Not a fully satisfying solution, but inheriting from AbstractAggregateRoot instead of redefining methods solved the issue for me.

Comment: @PostLoad is essentially simpler. It works with any entity, independent on inheritance.